# Php signup form doesn't work - Form just refreshes when input checks out requirement

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

The script doesn't throw any error, but if all the input fields are entered correctly, it just refreshs, and nothing happens.

I have included $salt and $link in header.php.

I might have overdid loops, but I spent couple of hrs trying to figure it out before posting it here.

```
<?php 
if (array_key_exists('username', $_POST)||array_key_exists('pass', $_POST)||array_key_exists('email', $_POST)) {

    if ($_POST["username"]!== "" && $_POST["email"]!== ""  && $_POST["pass"]!== "" && $_POST['cpass']!== "" ){

        if($_POST['pass']==$_POST['cpass']){

            if (!mysqli_connect_error()) {
                $query = "SELECT `username`, `email` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username'])."' OR `email` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."'";

                $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    if ($row['username'] == $_POST['username']) {
                        echo "Username already exists!<br>";
                    //die("Awe! Someone took this username");
                    }
                    if ($row['email'] == $_POST['email']) {
                        echo "Email has been used once!<br>";
                    //die(":( Email is in use!");
                    }else if($row['username'] !== $_POST['username'] && $row['email'] !== $_POST['email']){
                        $email    = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["email"]);
                        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["username"]);
                        $pass     = md5($salt.mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["pass"]));
                        $query    = "INSERT INTO `users`( `username`, `pass`, `email`) VALUES ('$username', '$pass', '$email')";        
                        if(mysqli_query($link, $query)){
                            echo "You were successfully registered";
                        } else {
                            echo "Something went wrong, Couldn't register at the moment!";
                        }
                    }

                }

            }else{
                echo "An Error Occured while connecting !";
            }



        }else {
            echo "Password didn't match!";

        }

    }else{
        echo "Field(s) can't be left blank!";

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: This (probably) won't fix your code, but why are you using `$pass` as the `email` column `('$username', '$pass', '$pass')` ?

Comment: Why the jquery tag? and where's the HTML form for this?

Comment: Thanks for noticing, Yeah I did this mistake while resetting code for posting here..

Comment: @Fred-ii-Added because it popped up in suggestion, removed the tag. i am certain that the name attributes in form are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of your code happens on :

`if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {`

and since you didn't place any else for this "if" you don't see anything happens.

The problem is, this condition becomes true only if email or username is already inside the table.

so if given username and/or email is not already in the table, this condition becomes false and therefore it never reaches to inside block where you want to insert the new data.

There is also a side issue with this and lets say your query fetch 2 rows.. imagine this table.

`userid  -  username - email 
1        - user1    - user1@test.com
2        - user2    - user2@test.com`

now lets say the given input data are

`$_POST['username'] = 'user1';
$_POST['email'] = 'user2@test.com';`

this will fetch 2 rows in your users table, but as you didn't make a loop you will only check for first row and it might cause bug or unexpected behavior in your script.

UPDATE : I also made a piece of code based on your code.. hope it helps you...

```
function validateInputs(){ 
    $keys = array('username','pass','cpass','email');
    foreach($keys as $key){
        if(!isset($_POST[$key]) || empty($_POST[$key])){
            throw new Exception("Field(s) can't be left blank!");
        }
    }
} 
function validatePassword(){
    if($_POST['pass'] !== $_POST['cpass']){
            throw new Exception("Password didn't match!");
    }
}
function checkForUniqueInput($email,$username){
    global $link;
    $query = "SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."' OR email = '".$email."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        throw new Exception("Username and/or email already exist");
    }
}
function insertNewUser($email,$username,$pass){
    global $link;
    $query    = "INSERT INTO users( username, pass, email) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$pass."', '".$email."')";     
    if(!mysqli_query($link, $query)){ 
        throw new Exception("Something went wrong, Couldn't register at the moment!"); 
    }
}

if(isset($_POST)){
    try{
        validateInputs();
        validatePassword();

        $email    = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["email"]);
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["username"]);
        $pass     = md5($salt.mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["pass"]));

        checkForUniqueInput($email,$username);
        insertNewUser($email,$username,$pass);
        echo 'You were successfully registered';
    } 
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo 'Error : '.$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mate, I'll try adding a while loop inside" if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { }"

Comment: Np :) the loop issue is not the main reason why your code doesn't work, the main reason is as you placed insert new data part inside of that "IF" while it only happens when your query brings and fetches a record from your table .

Comment: I also made a piece of code based on your code.. hope it helps you...

`

Comment: Thank you very much, I learned two things from this, over complicating code with loops is always bad, Should define functions to keep the code clean. Again a big Thank You, ^_^

Comment: Glad to hear that, Well I also used to code similarly specially whenever I wanted to code fast... :) maybe that's why I could understand your code issue :P hehe...

Comment: is it  a good practice to use try  and catch for telling user what went wrong ? Can this method be used in production site ? I have seen people just using loops and concatenating over an error variable.